# Is there an Esperanto online dictionary meta search?

Tags: websites, dictionaries

There are [various online dictionaries](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/3197/1576), and sometimes a word one is looking for can only be found in some or even only one of them.

Visiting all of those dictionaries to search through them for a specific word is tedious and one risks to forget about one that might be relevant (or to now even know about that particular online dictionary). Is there kind of a meta-search service that lets you search in all or at least several of these dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to their landing page, [ViVo (Vikia Vortaro)](http://kono.be/vivo/) searches for you in:

- [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/) (Reta Vortaro)
- [Vikipedio](http://wikipedia.org/) (Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia)
- [Majstro](http://www.majstro.com/Web/Majstro/sdict.php?gebrTaal=epo)
- [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/) (an IT dictionary, itself with various sources)
- [Lernu](http://eo.lernu.net/)
- [Wiktionary](http://eo.wiktionary.org/) (collaboratively created dictionary by the same organization as Wikipedia)
- [Glosbe](http://glosbe.com/)
- [LangSoft](http://slovnik.cz/)
- [EoRu.ru](http://eoru.ru/)
- [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/)
- [Encyclo-EN](http://encyclo.co.uk/)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://merriam-webster.com/) (a renown online English dictionary)
- [Encyclo-NL](http://encyclo.nl/)
- [Enzyklo-DE](http://enzyklo.nl/)
- [Bildvortaro de Esperanto (libro)](http://www.retbutiko.net/eo/ero/ebil)
- "la propra BiVo (BildVortaro)"

If it finds something, you can click on the result to see the source (e.g. the relevant ReVo page) in the right-hand frame, while the list of the meta-search results stays visible in the left-hand frame, so that you can also quickly switch between sources of results.